# gmaps4rails map does not show up while changing from rails 4.0.1 to 3.2.15

Tags: javascript, gmaps4rails

I made a stand alone app with gmaps4rails 1.5.6 and rails 4.0.1 for displaying locations on a map which worked perfectly. 
I repeated exactly what I did to integrate it with the main app which is in rails 3.2.15.
I removed the protected attributes gem from the gemfile as I was told this was only necessary for rails 4.
I think it may be a javascript issue.
This is my application.js:

```
//= require /gmaps4rails/googlemaps.js.coffee
//= require /gmaps4rails/mapquest.js.coffee
//= require /gmaps4rails/base.js.coffee
//= require /gmaps4rails/bing.js.coffee
//= require /gmaps4rails/openlayers.js.coffee
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require typeahead.min
```

I've also manually included the application.js file in the view

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

I get an empty white box but no map. 
In the standalone app running rails 4.0.1 I did not have to manually include the css stylesheet or the js but the map displayed fine. Here I've included both but the map still doesnt show up properly. The main app running rails 3.2.15 does use bootstrap and I've already added:

```
#map label { width: auto; display:inline; }
#map img { max-width: none; }
```

to my application.css file.
This is how I've called the map:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'gmaps4rails' %>
<%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>
```

I've been trying to resolve this issue for hours now and have had no luck. Is there anything else that could be the cause?

Even after adding all the js files manually to the view the map is still a blank white box:

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag "application",
 "gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base",
 "gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.googlemaps",
 "gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.bing",
 "gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.mapquest",
 "gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.openlayers" %>
```

Comment: did you put the `yield :scripts` necessary in versions < 2?

Comment: Yes, I did. In the application.html.erb in layouts.